# How to concatenate a list to a string in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm creating a md5 hash of some string in robot framework, and I want to split this hash and keep only the 32 first characters.

I'm trying with list and then cutting the list, but I can't concatenante the list back to a string. Here is my code :

```
${test1}=    Md 5    ${pwd_arg}
${test3}=    Hexdigest
${test4}=    Convert To List    ${test3}
${test5}=    Convert To String    ${test4}[0:32]
${test6}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=    ${test4}
```

Here are logs, basically I can cut the list but I can't concatenate all the elements on the list back to a string

```
INFO : ${test3} = 0e5751c026e543b2e8ab2eb06099daa1d1e5df47778f7787faab45cdf12fe3a8
INFO : ${test4} = ['0', 'e', '5', '7', '5', '1', 'c', '0', '2', '6', 'e', '5', '4', '3', 'b', '2', 'e', '8', 'a', 'b', '2', 'e', 'b', '0', '6', '0', '9', '9', 'd', 'a', 'a', '1', 'd', '1', 'e', '5', 'd', 'f', '4', '7',...
INFO : ${test5} = ['0', 'e', '5', '7', '5', '1', 'c', '0', '2', '6', 'e', '5', '4', '3', 'b', '2', 'e', '8', 'a', 'b', '2', 'e', 'b', '0', '6', '0', '9', '9', 'd', 'a', 'a', '1']
INFO : ${test6} = ['0', 'e', '5', '7', '5', '1', 'c', '0', '2', '6', 'e', '5', '4', '3', 'b', '2', 'e', '8', 'a', 'b', '2', 'e', 'b', '0', '6', '0', '9', '9', 'd', 'a', 'a', '1']
FAIL : b1404d6cc07abe3805e5960771c0ba72 != 0e5751c026e543b2e8ab2eb06099daa1d1e5df47778f7787faab45cdf12fe3a8
Ending test
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not familiar with the robot framework but wouldn't this return the list back to a string? `"".join(${test4}[0:32])`?

Comment: robot framework works with keywords, and i'm actually looking for this kind of keyword (join).

Comment: Using `Evaluate` seems to work to call the python `join` method. `${test5}=    Evaluate "".join(${test4}[0:32])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is a much easier way to slice a list in robot. And, `Convert to string` does not work the way you are intending to in your code.

Below is the code to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
${test4}=                 Convert To List      ${test3}
${test5}=                 Get Slice From List  ${test4}            0     32
${convertListToString}=   Evaluate             "".join(${test5})
${test6}=                 Catenate             SEPARATOR=   ${convertListToString}    ${otherStringToCatenate}
```

`Evaluate  "".join(${test5})` will convert the list to string and from there you can use the `Catenate` keyword to concatenate to the other string.

Answer (score 1):

To jump on the question as put - how to concatenate a list members in a string.
You were close - the keyword `Catenate` is very much suitable for that. You have to pass to it the different values to concatenate - and you were passing just a single one, the list variable itself. The easiest way to get all of them at once ("them" - the list members), is to use the format `@{a list variable}` - with the `@` prefix the framework will unpack the list - and pass all its members as separate arguments. So if your list variable is `${test4}`, the call would be

```
${test6}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=${EMPTY}    @{test4}
```

*(`${EMPTY}` is a system variable for the string `""` - an empty string, to be a bit more explicit in the intent.)*

This is quite similar to python's `"".join(an_iterable)` - in fact [the keyword's implemention does just that.](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/libraries/BuiltIn.py#L2526)

---

Apart from the question, it looks like your end goal was to get the first 32 characters from a string. If so, there is much more straightforward way to do that - just use the keyword [`Get Substring`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Substring); like this:

```
${substring}=    Get Substring    ${test3}    0    32
```